# Toyota Yaris rear bulb holder sourcing

Tags: toyota, parts, lights, tail-lights

I am looking to source an individual part for the rear drivers side tail/brake light. All I need is the bulb holder as all the electrical points in the one I have have rusted away. Unfortunately I have been unable to find one anywhere. Either online or locally.

I believe I can only possibly buy a replacement if I replace the whole lighting unit as pictured. But I really only need to one bulb holder. In the image below it would be the one to the far left.

[image]

Any advice would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you haven't tried a dealer parts department, I would suggest that first (taking some doughnuts may encourage them to spend time tracking down a part for you).  They really have the most complete parts databases, especially for body parts like this.  If you can get a part number from them, you can possibly find a cheaper source for it online (You want someplace that will sell you the part for a price somewhere between wholesale and retail, the closer to wholesale the better).  Some [forum posts](http://www.toyotaownersclub.com/forums/topic/41187-yaris-bulb-holders-and/) I saw indicate availability, for a price, though it wasn't clear to me if it was the whole assembly or the individual holders.  Given the complaints on pricing, I'd guess possibly the latter.

Most of the assemblies I see on eBay are without the bulb holders.  I suspect this is a common fault and a highly desired part.

You can always try a boneyard (junkyard).  If you're in the US, Pick-n-Pull is my favorite.  Given the eBay situation though, I suspect you may find the inventory picked over.  In that case, keep checking until a fresh one comes in and then head down and get to it before anybody else does.

Comment: Thanks for that advice, in the end I found the part from a breaker website online although I have to buy the whole unit. Like the one pictured rather than just the holder.